# How to insert sort function inside a for loop in Julia?

Tags: string, sorting, for-loop, julia

I'm playing a bit with strings in Julia and I make a simple for loop to store the frequency of some words in a dictionary.

Suppose I have this string

```
x="hola perro hola te huele tu patita perro perro cola colita hola hola hola sí como no"
```

Then I define y as split(x) and an empty dictionary

```
y=split(x, r"\W", keep=false)
c=Dict{String,Int64}()
```

Finally the loop and the sort function outside the loop in order to get the top 3 words:

```
for i in y
    c[i]=get(c,i,0)+1
end

c= sort(collect(c),by=tuple -> last(tuple),rev=true)[1:3]
```

When insert the last command inside the loop I got this error:

```
for i in y
    c[i]=get(c,i,0)+1
    c= sort(collect(c),by=tuple -> last(tuple),rev=true)[1:3]
end


BoundsError: attempt to access 1-element Array{Pair{String,Int64},1} at index [1:3]
```

Why is this happening? Why sort inside the for loops throws a BoundsError? Is it possible to accomplish what I want using any other method?
Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to achieve by moving a function that acts upon the entire dictionary inside a loop that iterates through it?

Comment: I just want that "c" gets retrieved by the for loop. That is, to get the same result that is obtained with what is showed in the third block with a single for loop.

Comment: First, in that case, the `sort` function would be called `i` times (even if it worked that way) instead of just once, which is probably what you don't need. Second, you simply cannot access elements 1 to 3 at a point where the dictionary you're constructing has only 1 or 2 elements.

Comment: I solved the problem defining a function. Anyway, I just wanted to know if it was possible to insert "sort" in a for loop. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

While `c` is a `Dict{String,Int64}()` the call to `c = sort(collect(c)...`) overrides it with a vectors of pairs (`Array{Pair{String,Int64},1}`). 
Therefore it is not work in a loop.

If you want to have a `Dict` containing only the 3 most frequent entries you could use:

```
c = Dict(sort(collect(c),by=tuple -> last(tuple),rev=true)[1:3])
```

But as you probably already know, `Dict` have no oder. There is `OrderedDict` from the module `DataStructures` for this.